# Kafka-Storm integration

Tags: maven, apache-storm

We have been trying to integrate kafka-storm by referring the Learning Storm book. We have followed all the steps but on execution of the following command we are getting 'Build Failure'-
mvn clean compile exec:java
-Dmain.class=com.learningstorm.kafka.KafkaTopology

### and the error is as follows-

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO]------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.546s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Jan 31 11:46:58 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/111M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project storm-example: The parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginParameterException
```

What should we do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried again by adding the dependency as specified by you but now it is giving an error in pom.xml and 'Build Failure' too .

Comment: Yes the issue has been resolved.We had to do  a lot of trial and error again.